# Refer to relationship in Laravel Eloquent scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel 5.7. I have a model `Cat`, with a property `visible`, and a scope to check for visibility:

```
class Cat extends Model
{
    public function scopeVisible($query)
    {
        return $query->where('visible', true);
    }

    public function fleas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Flea');
    }
}
```

I have a second model, `Flea`:

```
class Flea extends Model
{
    public function cat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cat');
    }
}
```

I want to add a similar visibility scope to `Flea`, so that I would be able to do something like `$fleas = Flea::visible()->get()`, which would only return Fleas which belong to visible Cats. But I'm not sure how I can reference the parent `Cat` in the scope method on `Flea`.

Edit: I try to access the `cat()` relationship in a `scopeVisible` method on `Flea`, but I get this error from Laravel:

> Property [cat] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
class Flea extends Model
{
    public function cat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cat');
    }

    public function scopeVisible($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('cat', function($query) {
            $query->visible();
        });
    }
}
```

Then just do:

```
Flea::visible()->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own query :

```
$fleas = Flea::whereHas('cat', function($q) {
    $q->where('visible', true);
})->get();
```

Or use the `Cat` model :

```
$cats = Cat::visible()->get();

foreach($cats as $cat) {
    foreach ($cat->fleas as $flea) {
        // only fleas with visible cats
    }
}
```

You can use the query as a local scope in the `Flea` model.